# Unexpected end of file - i cant find the issue

Tags: php, syntax-error, unexpectendoffile

Im getting the typical unexpected end of file
i cant see what I'm missing can someone else please help i've gone code blind

```
          <?php
      session_start();
      include('config.php');
      include('funcs.php');
      date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
      if(!in_array($_SESSION['userid'],$adminusr)){
      header("Location: index.html");
      }
      ?>
      <html><head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
          <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head><body>
          <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" style="height:55px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:#FF6600 2px solid;">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header" style="height:60px;">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-top:5px;"><img height="45" alt="Brand" src="logo.jpg"></a>
              </div>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Jobs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Servicing</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Prep</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Finances</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="addjob.php" class="btn btn-link" style="color:#ff6600;">+&nbsp;New Job</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="section">
            <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
              <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Jobs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Servicing</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Prep</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Finances</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="addjob.php" class="btn btn-link" style="color:#ff6600;">+&nbsp;New Job</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="section text-justify" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                  <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for something ...">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <a class="btn btn-link" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-search"></i></a>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="section text-center">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                  <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw fa-lg text-orange"></i>Current Jobs :</h3>
                    <?php 
                    // List Jobs With Closest Req. By Date 
                    $curdate = date('Y-m-d');
                    $listjobsq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE status != 'Completed' AND completed ='0' ORDER BY reqbydate ASC LIMIT 0,10");
                    $listjobs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listjobsq);

                    ?>
                  <ul class="list-group" style="border:none;">
                    <?php do { 
                    // Job Time Frame Check
                      $cur = strtotime($curdate);
                      $req = strtotime($listjobs['reqbydate']);
                      $diff = floor(abs($req - $cur) / 86400);
                      $diffdays = ' Days';
                      $diffbg = 'background-color:#1EBB1B; color:#000000;';
                      if($req < $cur) { $diff = 'OVERDUE';$diffdays = '';$diffbg = 'background-color:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF;';}
                      if($req == $cur) { $diff = 'TODAY';$diffdays = '';$diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';}
                      if($diff == 1) { $diff = 'TOMORROW';$diffdays = '';$diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';}
                      if($diff >= 2){ if($diff <= 7){$diffdays = ' Days';$diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';} } 


                    // End

                    // User Query
                    $wscid = $listjobs['wscid'];
                    $userq = mysqli_query($cona,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid = '$wscid'");
                    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userq);
                    ?>

                    <li class="list-group-item text-right" style="border:none;"><span class="badge pull-left" style="<?php echo $diffbg;?>"><?php echo $diff. $diffdays;?></span><a href="job.php?wsjid=<?php echo $listjobs['wsjid'];?>" style="color:#000;"><?php echo $user['forename'].' '.$user['surname'].' - ' .$listjobs['summary'];?></a></li>
                    <? } while($listjobs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listjobsq));?>
                    <li class="list-group-item text-center" style="border:none;"><a href="viewjobs.php" style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;"> -- View All Jobs -- </a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <hr>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                  <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-wrench text-orange"></i>Services / Work Due :</h3>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                  </ul>
                  <hr>
                </div>
                <!--?php if($_SESSION[ 'stafflvl']=='administrator' || $_SESSION[ 'stafflvl']=='superadministrator'
                ){ ?-->
                <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                  <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-money text-orange"></i>Finance &amp; Invoicing :</h3>
                  <ul class="list-group">
                  <?php 
                   $uninvoicedq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE completed = '1' AND invoiced = '0' AND wscid !='0' ORDER BY workstartdate ASC");
                    $uninvoiced = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uninvoicedq);
                  if($uninvoiced) {
                        do { 
                  // User Query
                    $wscid = $uninvoiced['wscid'];
                    $userq = mysqli_query($cona,"SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid = '$wscid'");
                    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userq);
                    $wtbdq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE wsjid = '$uninvoiced[wsjid]'");
                              $wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq);
                                 do {
                                     $price = '';
                              $wtbd = explode(":",$wtbdr['worktobedone']);

                              foreach($wtbd as $item) 
                                  {
                                      $priceq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `workshop-items` WHERE wsiid = '$item'");
                                      $pricer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceq);

                                      $price[] = $pricer['incvat'];
                                      $items[] = $pricer['description'];

                                      //echo $item.' - '. $pricer['incvat'].'<br>';
                                      $total = array_sum($price);
                                  }


                              } while($wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq));
              ?>
              <?


              $itemList = implode(":",$items);
              $itemview = str_replace(":","\n",$itemList);

                  ?>
                    <li class="list-group-item text-right" style="border:none;" title="<?php echo $itemview;?>"><span class="badge pull-left" style="background-color:#F00;">Not Invoiced</span><?php echo '&pound;'.$total.' - '; echo $user['forename'].' '.$user['surname'].' - ' .$uninvoiced['summary'];?> </li>
                    <? } while($uninvoiced = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uninvoicedq));} else { echo "No Jobs Waiting To Invoiced";}?>
                  </ul>
                  <hr>
                </div>
                <?php  //echo $_SESSION[ 'admin'];?-->?>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </body></html>
```

I have looked over all of my code but i am pulling my hair out now.. 
could really do with a fresh pair of eyes having a gander please

Comment: `if($uninvoiced) {` this curly braces not closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
include('funcs.php');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
if (!in_array($_SESSION['userid'], $adminusr)) {
    header("Location: index.html");
}
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
    <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"
     style="height:55px; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-bottom:#FF6600 2px solid;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="height:60px;">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-top:5px;"><img height="45" alt="Brand" src="logo.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Jobs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Servicing</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Prep</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Finances</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="addjob.php" class="btn btn-link" style="color:#ff6600;">+&nbsp;New Job</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Jobs</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Servicing</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Prep</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Finances</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="addjob.php" class="btn btn-link" style="color:#ff6600;">+&nbsp;New Job</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="section text-justify" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for something ...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <a class="btn btn-link" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-search"></i></a>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="section text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw fa-lg text-orange"></i>Current Jobs :</h3>
                <?php
                // List Jobs With Closest Req. By Date
                $curdate = date('Y-m-d');
                $listjobsq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE status != 'Completed' AND completed ='0' ORDER BY reqbydate ASC LIMIT 0,10");
                $listjobs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listjobsq);

                ?>
                <ul class="list-group" style="border:none;">
                    <?php do {
                        // Job Time Frame Check
                        $cur = strtotime($curdate);
                        $req = strtotime($listjobs['reqbydate']);
                        $diff = floor(abs($req - $cur) / 86400);
                        $diffdays = ' Days';
                        $diffbg = 'background-color:#1EBB1B; color:#000000;';
                        if ($req < $cur) {
                            $diff = 'OVERDUE';
                            $diffdays = '';
                            $diffbg = 'background-color:#FF0000; color:#FFFFFF;';
                        }
                        if ($req == $cur) {
                            $diff = 'TODAY';
                            $diffdays = '';
                            $diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';
                        }
                        if ($diff == 1) {
                            $diff = 'TOMORROW';
                            $diffdays = '';
                            $diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';
                        }
                        if ($diff >= 2) {
                            if ($diff <= 7) {
                                $diffdays = ' Days';
                                $diffbg = 'background-color:#F8C000; color:#000000;';
                            }
                        }


                        // End

                        // User Query
                        $wscid = $listjobs['wscid'];
                        $userq = mysqli_query($cona, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid = '$wscid'");
                        $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userq);
                        ?>

                        <li class="list-group-item text-right" style="border:none;"><span class="badge pull-left"
                                                                                          style="<?php echo $diffbg; ?>"><?php echo $diff . $diffdays; ?></span><a
                                    href="job.php?wsjid=<?php echo $listjobs['wsjid']; ?>"
                                    style="color:#000;"><?php echo $user['forename'] . ' ' . $user['surname'] . ' - ' . $listjobs['summary']; ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } while ($listjobs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listjobsq)); ?>
                    <li class="list-group-item text-center" style="border:none;"><a href="viewjobs.php"
                                                                                    style="color:#000; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;">
                            -- View All Jobs -- </a></li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-wrench text-orange"></i>Services / Work Due :</h3>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <!--?php if($_SESSION[ 'stafflvl']=='administrator' || $_SESSION[ 'stafflvl']=='superadministrator'
            ){ ?-->
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left">
                <h3>
                    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-money text-orange"></i>Finance &amp; Invoicing :</h3>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <?php
                    $uninvoicedq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE completed = '1' AND invoiced = '0' AND wscid !='0' ORDER BY workstartdate ASC");
                    $uninvoiced = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uninvoicedq);
                    if ($uninvoiced) {
                        do {
                            // User Query
                            $wscid = $uninvoiced['wscid'];
                            $userq = mysqli_query($cona, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE userid = '$wscid'");
                            $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userq);
                            $wtbdq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `workshop-jobs` WHERE wsjid = '$uninvoiced[wsjid]'");
                            $wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq);
                            do {
                                $price = '';
                                $wtbd = explode(":", $wtbdr['worktobedone']);

                                foreach ($wtbd as $item) {
                                    $priceq = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `workshop-items` WHERE wsiid = '$item'");
                                    $pricer = mysqli_fetch_assoc($priceq);

                                    $price[] = $pricer['incvat'];
                                    $items[] = $pricer['description'];

                                    //echo $item.' - '. $pricer['incvat'].'<br>';
                                    $total = array_sum($price);
                                }


                            } while ($wtbdr = mysqli_fetch_assoc($wtbdq));
                            ?>
                            <?php


                            $itemList = implode(":", $items);
                            $itemview = str_replace(":", "\n", $itemList);

                            ?>
                            <li class="list-group-item text-right" style="border:none;"
                                title="<?php echo $itemview; ?>"><span class="badge pull-left"
                                                                       style="background-color:#F00;">Not Invoiced</span><?php echo '&pound;' . $total . ' - ';
                                echo $user['forename'] . ' ' . $user['surname'] . ' - ' . $uninvoiced['summary']; ?>
                            </li>
                        <?php } while ($uninvoiced = mysqli_fetch_assoc($uninvoicedq));
                    } else {
                        echo "No Jobs Waiting To Invoiced";
                    } ?>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <?php //echo $_SESSION[ 'admin'];?-->?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

try this once

Comment: works ! thanks where was I missing a closing tag out of curiosity ?

Comment: no you were missing some php tags, great to know have helped you

Comment: i've gone totally code blind i still cant see it in original code lol.
Many thanks for your help.. could feel a headache coming on.
will accept answer as soon as it lets me

Comment: it happens bro, dont worry :) @ChrisYates

Answer (score 0):

tou are missing a `}` at end. make sure that you ended `if($uninvoiced) {` on line 152.